# How do I annotate protocols and their methods in Clojure's core.typed?

Tags: clojure, type-systems, lighttable, clojure-core.typed

I am making a tic tac toe game and have made a protocol for my Strategy. The game is running fine, so I want to take this opportunity to hone my core.typed skills. I have annotated the protocol (as shown below), but when I run `(cf method-name)` or `(cf protocol-name)` in the repl, I get this error:

eg:

```
=> `(cf win)`
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Type Checker: Found 1 error :: {:type-error :top-level-error, :errors (#<ExceptionInfo clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Unannotated var tic-tac-toe.protocol/win
Hint: Add the annotation for tic-tac-toe.protocol/win via check-ns or cf {:env {:file "/Users/jessediaz/Documents/workspace/tic-tac-toe/src/tic_tac_toe/protocol.clj", :column 5, :line 47}, :form win, :type-error :clojure.core.typed.errors/tc-error-parent}>)}
```

I have checked to make sure that the version of protocol is in fact core.typed/protocol. The console barked at me when I used protocol> saying the syntax was deprecated. I have also looked through the documentation on both the github page and clojure-doc.org. This is how I learned that there is an optional `:methods` keyword that I can use to map methods to types. I feel that this might remove a lot of repetition from my code, but I haven't been able to find any examples of its usage. the main strategy methods in the protocol all have side effects and return `nil`. The validation methods either return `nil` or the original `Strategy` methods that they validating. I am not sure I have the syntax right there, but the code is evaluating fine in LightTable, with or without the `Fn` signature, and they the core.typed wiki implies that it is not always necessary.

I feel like I am on the cusp here in learning this amazing library and would appreciate any insightful advice that could help my understanding.

protocol.clj file:

```
(ns tic-tac-toe.protocol
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :refer :all]))

(ann-protocol Strategy
                win                        (Fn [Strategy -> nil])
                block                      (Fn [Strategy -> nil])
                fork                       (Fn [Strategy -> nil])
                block-fork                 (Fn [Strategy -> nil])
                take-center                (Fn [Strategy -> nil])
                take-opposite-corner       (Fn [Strategy -> nil])
                take-corner                (Fn [Strategy -> nil])
                take-side                  (Fn  [Strategy -> nil])

                can-win?                   (Fn [Strategy -> (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil]))])
                can-block?                 (Fn [Strategy -> (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil]))])
                can-fork?                  (Fn [Strategy -> (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil]))])
                can-block-fork?            (Fn [Strategy -> (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil]))])
                can-take-center?           (Fn [Strategy -> (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil]))])
                can-take-corner?           (Fn [Strategy -> (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil]))])
                can-take-side?             (Fn [Strategy -> (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil]))]))
(defprotocol Strategy
  "Strategy methods update the Tic-tac-toe board when they are called"

  ;; strategies
  (win [_] "wins the game by filling an open space to get 3 in a row")
  (block [_] "blocks an opponents win by filling an open space")
  (fork [_] "creates a two way win scenario guaranteeing victory")
  (block-fork [_] "prevents an opponent from forking")
  (take-center [_] "takes center")
  (take-opposite-corner [_] "takes a corner opposite to one the computer already has")
  (take-corner [_] "takes an avaiable corner")
  (take-side [_] "takes an available side")

  ;; tests
  (can-win? [_])
  (can-block? [_])
  (can-fork? [_])
  (can-block-fork? [_])
  (can-take-center? [_])
  (can-take-opposite-corner? [_])
  (can-take-corner? [_])
  (can-take-side? [_]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to `check-ns` the current namespace before querying it with `cf`. Evaluation of typed code does not trigger type checking or annotation collection.

The `ann-protocol` is not needed here, `clojure.core.typed/defprotocol` supports inline annotation.

Try something like:

```
(defprotocol Strategy
  "Strategy methods update the Tic-tac-toe board when they are called"

  ;; strategies
  (win [_] :- nil "wins the game by filling an open space to get 3 in a row")
  (block [_] :- nil "blocks an opponents win by filling an open space")
  ...)
```

Comment: Are the input types for those methods inferred?

Comment: The 'self' types are inferred, and cannot be overridden (yet!) directly in defprotocol. For non-polymorphic protocols 'self' is Strategy, otherwise it's (Strategy a b c) assuming the protocol is parameterised by a, b and c.

Comment: All parameters after the 1st are *not* inferred however.

Comment: That makes sense. But what if I am returning  either nil or a Strategy method, would I annotate it :-  (U nil [nil]) or something?

Comment: nm I figured it out. ':- (U nil (Fn [Strategy -> nil])' Thanks a bunch man!